# How to test a method invocation inside an anonymous class using mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void exe() {
        try {
            Reserve reserveInfo = newTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Reserve>() {
                @Override
                public Reserve doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                    return reserveService.callReserve(reserveDetails);
                }
            });
            if(reserveInfo != null && reserveInfo.getStatus()=="DONE") {
            someOtherService.doSomething();
            }
        } finally {
            if(reserveInfo!= null && reserveInfo.getStatus().equals("DONE")){
                final String id = reserveInfo.getId();                                  
                Release releaseInfo = newTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Release>() {
                    @Override
                    public Release doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                        return reserveService.callRelease(id);
                    }
                });             
                if (releaseInfo.getStatus() != "RELEASED") {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Problem in releaseing");

                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

This is the sample code I want to test. I couldn't find much on testing anonymous class on net. 
I want to test the exe() method, go through newTransactionTemplate.execute method and mock the call to reserveService.callReserve(reserveDetails).

Can any body please suggest how can I test this situation?

here is the sample how i'm trying to test:

```
 private SomeService someService = null;
    @Mock
    private ReserveService mockReserveService;
    @Mock
    private ReleaseService mockReleaseService;
    @Mock
    private TransactionTemplate mockTransactionTemplate;
    @Mock
    private SomeOtherService mockSomeOtherService;    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() throws Exception {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);   
       someService = new SomeService();
       someService.setReserveService(mockReserveService);
       someService.setReleaseService(mockReleaseService);
       someService.setSomeOtherService(mockSomeOtherService);
       someService.setNewTransactionTemplate(mockTransactionTemplate);
    }
    @Test(enabled=true)
    public void exeHappyPath() {
        Reserve reserveInfo = new Reserve();
        reserveInfo.setId("123");
        reserveInfo.setStatus("DONE");
        Release releaseInfo = new Release();
        releaseInfo.setStatus("RELEASED");
        when(mockReserveService.callReserve(Mockito.any(ReserveDetails.class))).thenReturn(reserveInfo);
        when(mockReserveService.callRelease(reserveInfo.getId())).thenReturn(releaseInfo);
        when(mockTransactionTemplate.execute(Mockito.<TransactionCallback<Reserve>>any())).thenReturn(reserveInfo);
        when(mockTransactionTemplate.execute(Mockito.<TransactionCallback<ReleaseInfo>>any())).thenReturn(releaseInfo);
        //Call the exe method
        someService.exe();

        verify(mockReserveService, times(1)).callReserve(Mockito.any(ReserveDetails.class));
        verify(mockReserveService, times(1)).callRelease(reserveInfo.getId())); 
        verify(mockSomeOtherService, times(1)).doSomthing());

    }
```

The second call to when(mockTransactionTemplate.execute.. with return object releaseInfo
throws java.lang.ClassCastException:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the solution to the above mentioned scenario. As I was not interested in testing the invocation of **newTransactionTemplate.execute()**, it being an spring API. I wanted to test the invocation of **reserveService.callReserve(reserveDetails)** and **reserveService.callRelease(id)**. 
The only way to test this is if we create a transactiontemplate/transactioncallback "real" implementation/stub that is just pass thru. so the doIntransaction method should do nothing more than execute the action. then we can set expectation on the action methods which in this case is the **reserveService**.

```
    when(mockTransactionTemplate.execute(Mockito.<TransactionCallback>any())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
         public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
             Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
           TransactionCallback arg = (TransactionCallback)args[0];
             return arg.doInTransaction(new SimpleTransactionStatus());
         }
     });     
    when(mockResourceService.callReserve(any(ReserveDetails.class))).thenReturn(reserveInfo);
    when(mockResourceService.callRelease(eq(id))).thenReturn(releaseInfo);

    //Call the exe method
    someService.exe();

    verify(mockResourceService, times(1)).callReserve(any(ReserveDetails.class));
    verify(mockSomeOtherService, times(1)).doSomthing());
    verify(mockMemberResourceService, times(1)).callRelease(eq(id));
```

Comment: Thank you Anj. This mocking in Java 8   `when(transactionTemplate.execute(Mockito.<TransactionCallback>any())).thenAnswer((Answer) invocation -> {
   final TransactionCallback txCallback = (TransactionCallback) invocation.getArguments()[0];
   return txCallback.doInTransaction(new SimpleTransactionStatus());
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Where does `reserveService` come from? If you are injecting it through either `SomeClass`'s constructor or a setter, you can pass a mock instead.

```
// Set up your mock and stub out the method call
ReserveService reserveService = mock(ReserveService.class);
when(reserveService.callReserve(any(ReserveDetails.class))).thenReturn(null);

// Inject, either via constructor or setter
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass(reserveService);
// Or, instance.setReserveService(reserveService);
```

Comment: Yes..ReserveService is injected through through the property.

Comment: Yes..ReserveService is injected through through the property. will this test cover the call to newTransactionTemplate.execte() method which is also injected through the property.

Comment: `ReserveService reserveService = mock(ReserveService.class);
TransactionTemplate newTransactionTemplate = mock(TransactionTemplate.class);

SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
instance.setReserveService(reserveService);
instance.setNewTransactionTemplate(newTransactionTemplate);`

You can now call `SomeClass#exe()` but I'm not exactly what this will do for you. What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: i tried what you just mentioned, but that returns null for the newTransactionTemplate.execte() call. I can stub it to return Reserve type but then reserveService.callReserve() will not be tested. I may even live with that, but there is one more problem I call newTransactionTemplate.execute twice in the code with different return type. Which brakes the test as newTransactionTemplate.execute has just return type different but the method signature are same both the times.

Comment: eg.              1st call: Reserve reserveInfo = newTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Reserve>() {
            @Override
            public Reserve doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                return reserveService.callReserve(reserveDetails);
            }
        });
2nd call: Release releaseInfo = newTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Release>() {
            @Override
            public Release doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                return reserveService.callRelease(id);
            }
        });

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to test - if you tell me, I can try to help. What method are you trying to test and what is the assertion you are trying to verify?

Comment: i'm basically trying to test exe() method of SomeClass class. there is some scenario in code based on the return object from reserveService.callReserve and reserveService.CallRelease so i was thinking of mocking it as, i just care about the return object from these two calls.

Comment: Is there a way i can share my code with u so u have a better view of what is happening.

Comment: here is sample of what i'm doing

Comment: I have updated the code sample above to include how i'm testing. If that gives you a little more incite to wht i'm trying to test.

Comment: That is because you are stubbing it to return a `Release` instance but the code you are testing expects it to return a `Reserve` instance. Even though it looks like you are stubbing it to return something different based on the argument passed to the method, it doesn't work as you're expecting because generics are only available at compile time and not runtime. So any time you pass a `TransactionCallback` to the `execute` method your mock will return a `Release`.

Comment: i had figured that out..I was looking at the way out.

Comment: How do I test my exe() of SomeClass in this situation?

Comment: Remove the stubbing and verifying that deals with `Release` instances from your test case. There are not any `Release` instances used anywhere in the method you are trying to test.

Comment: there is call to release i had just not mentioned in the sample code. I just updated the code to show that little bit.